# Gunicorn is printing logs multiple times

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have an application which is running on top of `Python, Flask and Gunicorn`. For each request logger is printing `logs multiple times`. Logs are printing the same number of times as I have `workers` for Gunicorn. As I keep changing workers, logs printing will also change.
How to remove multiple logging?
Also how can I be sure that not each request is served by every worker?
I used the follwoing log settings :

```
handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(filename,'d',1, 7)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter(
    "[%(asctime)s] {%(pathname)s:%(lineno)d} %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
app.logger.addHandler(handler)
app.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
```

Comment: The problem is almost certainly that each request is served by each worker and nothing to do with logging. Can you print your guincorn conf file and the command you use to run it

Comment: exec /usr/local/bin/gunicorn agent_api:app -b 0.0.0.0:8983 --name $NAME --workers $NUM_WORKERS -D --access-logfile $ACCESSLOG --error-logfile $ERRORLOG --log-level=info -p $PIDFILE --keep-alive 1 --limit-request-line 0 --timeout 10000 --pythonpath $PYTHONPATH

Comment: Is there any way that I can print worker id in the logs?

Comment: Did you put `app.run()` inside `if name == "__main__"`? It looks like you didn't, and when gunicorn loads app module, it accidentally execute `app.run()`, thus having two app instances. (just a guess)

Comment: yes its inside the main

Comment: Hey @Neel, did you ever figure this out/

Comment: @MatthewMoisen didn't find it, but I changed the log settings and it worked

Comment: @neel, would you mind posting your log settings as an edit to your question? I would love to try it.

Comment: @MatthewMoisen I edited the question.